# group by a column based on a value to a group and all the other as another

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which a column has values like below.

```
mango
orange
mango
banana
grape
pineapple
```

So, I want the result as

```
mango
other
```

how can i group this column based on these values.What is the query or is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(`fruit` = 'mango', `fruit`, 'other') AS `someName`, count(*) as `total`
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY `someName`;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/826a0/1)